# Is it possible to define non-admin user interface like activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm making an application using rails and activeadmin. I want to use the same interface for both admin and non-admin users.

Is it possible to call the methods show, index, column, attribute_table, etc, from outside activeadmin?

For example, I'd like to make an index page for users like this:

```
<%= index @users do
  column :name
  column :last_name
  column :email do |user|
    link_to user.email , user_path(user)
  end
  column :status
end %>
```

Comment: http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/building-web-apps-with-activeadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to define the whole application with ActiveAdmin.

Steps:

1. Define methods for authentication and current user depending on the namespace:

   ```
   #config/initializers/active_admin.rb
   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
       admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
       admin.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
   end
   config.namespace false do |c|
       c.authentication_method = :logged_in?
       c.current_user_method = :current_user
   end
   ```
2. Configure folders:

   ```
   #config/initializers/active_admin.rb
   config.load_paths = [File.expand_path('app/admin', Rails.root), File.expand_path('app/users', Rails.root),]
   ```
3. Define pages and resources for admins under `app/admin` using `ActiveAdmin.register Resource do` and `ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Page name' do`
4. Define pages and resources for non-admin users under `app/users` using `ActiveAdmin.register Resource , namespace: false do` and `ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Page name' , namespace: false do`